# Como concatenar sem alterar o conteudo existente

Tags: javascript, html

O meu objetivo é que ao clicar no botão cinza adicionar um postit sem alterar o que já la está, usando o loop e o += para concatenar vai alterar o que já está lá, queria saber se há mais alguma opção para poder concatenar usando o loop sem haver nenhuma alteração

```js
function enable() {
  document.querySelector('.btn-escrever').disabled = false;
}

var btn = document.querySelector(".btn-apagar");
btn.addEventListener("click", remove);
var textotitle = document.querySelector(".tarefas");

function remove() {
  textotitle.parentNode.removeChild(textotitle);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* outline: 1px solid tomato; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.emcima {
  max-width: 64rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.espaco {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

body {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 20px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.A {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
}

.titulo {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.btn-mais {
  border: 0;
  color: #111111;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tarefa {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.btn-escrever,
.btn-apagar {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="emcima">
  
<div class='A'>
    <h1>Tarefas</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn-mais">Adicionar</button>
</div>
    <div class='espaco'>
    <ul class="tarefas">
      
      <li class="tarefa">
        
        <header>
          <input type="text" class="titulo" placeholder="Título">
          <button type="button" onclick="enable()" class="btn-escrever">✒️</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn-apagar">✂️</button>
        </header>
        <textarea name="" placeholder="Texto da tarefa" class='texto'></textarea>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - a var textotitle deveria estar dentro da função remove

2 - acho que já viciei em jquery, mas seria isso com ele:

```
$('.tarefa').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.tarefas');
```

mas eu alteraria o tarefas para id e não class pois acredito que não exista mais de uma classe com este nome